# How can I autocomplete file names with special characters in Powershell?

Tags: powershell, script, autocomplete

Say I am trying to replace files with placeholder files with the same name. If I have a file called "example.mp4" I can simply type in `>Clear-Content e` and tab complete from there, but if I have another file called "[DEMO VIDEOS] example2.mp4", I cannot tab complete after typing in a bracket.

Trying to tab complete at `>Clear-Content .\` and cycling results in `` >Clear-Content '.\`[DEMO VIDEOS] example2.mp4 `` but tab completion doesn't work with `` >Clear-Content '.\`[ ``.

I've tried this with the vanilla PSReadLine and https://github.com/lzybkr/PSReadLine but I haven't been able to find a solution.

Comment: ```Clear-Content '.\``[```<Tab>

Comment: @PetSerAl This works. If possible, could you please explain why two escapes are needed and how this works?